# Full screen at the application opening

Tags: python

I would like blender to be always opened in full screen. I don't find this option in the user preferences, but maybe it is possible directly from the code ? I am on blender 2.79. If you have any idea ! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you save the start-up file in full screen it will start in full screen at least on win10.

Comment: So simple.. thank you for your answer !